# Sun explaining interposing

Tags: java, proxy

Please refer to http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/Interposing/

And then the following explanation:

> At class load time, the interposed class must be found before the
>   original one...The interposed class must have the same full name as
>   the original. For example, a class Foo may exist in package pub.foo
>   and create an instance of class Bar from package pub.bar. Creating a
>   file Bar.java in another directory, such as fake/pub/bar and
>   prepending /fake to the classpath, ensures that the JVM will load our
>   definition of class pub.bar.Bar rather than the original. In this way,
>   we can interpose our definitions of Bar's methods over the originals.

In the example that follows Bar.java is the interface - the object of which would be interposed.

I cannot understand what use case is Sun explaining in the quote above. Specific doubts: 
1. Which is the original class being mentioned? 
2. In what case would I need to have my own fake/pub.bar.Bar and not use the original one (in case i have interpreted the meaning of original correctly). Please explain with example if possible.

Thanks in advane

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're mixing up two ways of proxy creation: CGLib and runtime proxy. First one creates proxy while your class is being loaded and the second one as it name says does it in a runtime. They are the same in a way that both of they are creating transparent proxy around your object, but there are some significant differences between them. For example, CGlib requires a class to be non-final and have default constructor. Or let's consider following example. Let's say you have a service `MyService`:

```
public class MyService {
    @Transactional
    public void proxifiedMethod(){
         // some logic here    
    }

    public void pureMethod(){
        // some logic here...
        proxifiedMethod();
        // ...and here
    }
}
```

Let's say you need `proxifiedMethod` to run inside a transaction and you give a hint to a framework you use with `@Transactional` annotation. If the framework (let's say Spring) is confiured to use runtime proxies, a transaction for the `proxifiedMethod` which is invoked from `pureMethod` won't be created, in case of CGLib it will.

Answering your questions:

1. Original class is a class around instance of which the proxy object is created.
2. Runtime proxies you're referring to are widely used in Java enterprise world when it comes to such [cross-cutting concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) as transactions or security. Usually you don't want to mess your code with manual transaction management, it's something that's done by a framework like Spring or even an application container like JBoss. So you add some meta information like `@Transactional` annotation, and framework creates a proxy around your annotated service to handle logic of transaction management there.

Comment: Thanks. It was my bad to have posted the doubt under a wrong heading (now altered). I have been reading the article over and over again and now have doubts related to Class Loading. Why is it said that the Proxy class should be loaded before the actual one? Is it because it will be used before the original one. Also what is the significance of providing the classloader to the newProxyInstance method? Thanks again.